# break-down complexity of BST traversal

Tags: python, recursion, big-o, time-complexity

I have the following BST traversal function in Python:

```
def print_tree(tree):
    if tree == None:
        return
    else:
        print tree.value
        print_tree(tree.left)
        print_tree(tree.right)
```

The worst-case time complexity is `O(n)`, but I am having a hard time proving it. I am attempting to break it down using constants, `c`, this is what I have:

```
T(n) = 2T(n-1) + cn
```

Where `T(n)` for both recursive calls, and `cn` for the print statement. But this does not seem to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recurrence relation should be

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + cn
```

Then from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25875038/1539655)
you can solve your recurrence relation. Let's assume that cn = Θ(1)

```
T(n)=2T(n/2)+Θ(1)
     =2T(n/2)+k
     =2{2T(n/4)+k)+k
     =4T(n/4)+3k
     =...
     =n.T(1)+(n-1)k
     =n.k+(n-1)k
     =2nk-k
     =O(n).
```

Answer (score 2):

Just expand the recurrence relation:

```
T(1) = c*n
T(2) = 3*c*n
T(3) = 7*c*n
T(4) = 15*c*n
...
```

As you can see, you never get terms than are not linear in `n`.

Intuitively, the complexity is linear since you do a constant amount of work per node and never visit a node more than once.

If the tree is balanced, the recurrence relation becomes

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + cn
```

and can be solved using the the [master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) (Case 1) to give `O(n)`.